# Making a 'flip-book' type animation using density plots from R

Tags: r, animation, ggplot2

I'm new to R, but have worked out how to graph the distribution of my students' grades for a given term using a density plot, and have made some ridgeline plots to show how the distribution evolves throughout the academic year.

I'm thinking it might be fun (and make the graphs easier to interpret) if I could make a kind of flip-book animation that went from one terms grades to the next, relatively quickly, to see how the distribution changes.  At its simplest, I could just pop these distribution plots into Powerpoint and just scroll through the pages, but I'm wondering what commands I need to put into R's ggplot command to ensure that the axes/scaling from one chart to the next stays consistent from one chart to the next?

At the moment, I'm just making a simple chart using this command, where HT102 is the data from the 2nd term of Year 10, and A8 is a vector containing all the (numeric) grades.  I am then doing the same thing with another set of grades called ht103, and so on...

```
ggplot(ht102, aes(x = A8)) +
         geom_density(alpha=.3)
```

What would you recommend to keep the scaling consistent, and any thoughts on a better way to animate this than just popping them into powerpoint?

Comment: I'd recommend doing a little searching. You just need to set the axis limits for you ggplots, see `?scale_x_continuous` and the `y` counterpart. Similarly, if you search for "animate plot R" the first hits will probably be several examples of how to use the `animate` package... Come back with a specific question if you have an attempt and get stuck along the way. Share code and sample data and we'll help you work through it.

Comment: Check out the [`gganimate` package](http://www.ggplot2-exts.org/gganimate.html), developed for just what you're trying to do